# Java - need help using JScrollPane in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I'm new to java & am trying to make a chat GUI.
I've encountered a problem trying to add a JScrollPane to my JTextArea, here is the code:

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener, WindowListener{

```
private static JFrame frame;
private static JTextField typeField;
private static JTextArea textArea;
private static JScrollPane scroll;
private static JButton b1;
private static int width = 500, height = 800;
private static String appTitle = "test";

public Test(){
    // frame
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(height, width);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setTitle(appTitle);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            // type field
            typeField = new JTextField();
            typeField.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            typeField.addKeyListener(this);
            typeField.setSize(440, 27);
            typeField.setLocation(9, 435);
            typeField.addActionListener(this);
            // text area
            textArea = new JTextArea();
            textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            textArea.setSize(464, 400);
            textArea.setLocation(10, 30);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            // button
            b1 = new JButton("^");
            b1.addMouseListener(this);
            b1.setSize(41, 26);
            b1.setLocation(453, 435);
            // scrollpane
            scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scroll.setSize(18, 400);
            scroll.setLocation(476, 31);

            // add elements
            frame.add(typeField);
            frame.add(textArea);
            frame.add(scroll);
            frame.add(b1);

            frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main (String args[]){
    new Test();
}
public void textSent() {
    String senttxt = typeField.getText();
    if (senttxt.equals("")) {
    } else {
        textArea.append("{User}: " + senttxt + "\n\n");
        typeField.setText("");
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    textSent();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    textSent();
}

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}
```

}

the scrollbar is there but when the text fills up the text area, I can't scroll down.
Could someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: First issue `frame.setLayout(null);`

Comment: Second issue `frame.add(textArea); frame.add(scroll);`

Comment: Third issue `b1.addMouseListener(this);` ... use an `ActionListener`

Comment: Fourth issue `typeField.addKeyListener(this);` ... `KeyListener` is never a good choice for text components, use an `ActionListener` and/or `DocumentListener` and/or `DocumentFilter` depending on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Start with [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) then have a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for a better understanding of how to use scroll panes. Basically, a component can only reside within a single parent, so when you call `add(textArea)`, you remove it from the `JScrollPane`